# My mouse is moving very hardly and slow, just at the moment i am rendering an image

Tags: rendering

As Title says, My mouse is pretty snaily when Im rendering, even when Im not inside blender, it just makes my mouse go superslow, and it ruins my everyday rendering life.

Comment: In general OS takes care of at least some CPU interruptions to allow its own elements like windows and mouse to be drawn more or less constantly. So even while rendering your mouse pointer should move normal **if rendering is the only hungry process**. It's very likely that there are some other problems aside from rendering. There aren't any details like OS and hardware specs in your question; You could [edit] your question with some.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is normal behavior when rendering complex scenes, especially on weaker computers.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This isn't something you can fix really because rendering is a very large computing process you should either buy a computer with better specs or deal with the lag

Comment: Sure it can be fixed: set process priority low, do not render on all cores/threads if also working on the machine while rendering, etc. Better specs won't fix it at all, because Blender will use all the available compute power anyway, even with better specs, resulting in the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the task manager and begin to render something. Right click on the blender task that is taking the most processing power and press "go to details". When you have done that you should see a lot of programs and one of them will be marked(blender will be marked). Right click on it and go to 'set priority'  and set the priority to something low.

Now its fixed(hopefully) but your renders might take longer. Though I'm not sure if it's a noticeable amount slower.